# Movesense remove individual datalogger entries

Tags: movesense

I am using the Movesense Sensor HR+ with Datalogger and Android API. Sometimes I need to have 2 separate data log entries and I want to remove only one of them and keep the other. The steps are as follows:

1. Stop current logEntry1 from recording (log entry with id=1)
2. Start recording a new logEntry2 (log entry with id=2)
3. Start download of logEntry1
4. Ensure logEntry1 download completes without connectivity breaks
5. Delete logEntry1 from movesense device

I only seem to be able to erase all logs via the Andorid API on movesense using: `suunto://{0}/Mem/Logbook/Entries`

But, I would like to be able to use something like this: `suunto://MDS/Logbook/{0}/ById/{1}/Data`
Where:
`{0}` is the movesense device number
`{1}` is the log entry Id.

I haven't got it to work yet. Is it possible?

Thanks!
Helic

Answer (score 0):

The current Movesense sensor organizes the Logbook as a ring-buffer and it is not possible to delete individual logs. However that means that DataLogger will just overwrite the oldest log so there is no real need to delete the logs.

What you need is to keep track on mobile side which logs you have fetched from the sensor and just let the sensor overwrite them when the time comes.

This overwriting means that it is not advisable (read: "bad things can happen#) to read the oldest log if new data is being written to the Logbook. To avoid this, check the */Mem/Logbook/IsFull* (GET / SUBSCRIBE) to see if overwriting is happening and if it is, just postpone starting new log if that is the case.

*Full Disclosure: I work for the Movesense team*

Comment: Hi PetriL. Thanks for the fast response. In v1.9.7 have tried /Mem/Logbook/IsFull & its always false (probably because it's a ring buffer & thus never full). Our movesense device communicates with a mobile once every 12 hours & we log rr interval non-stop for 3 weeks. rrIntervals have no id or timestamp to check if the overwrite has taken place. I guess the best way to approach my problem is: stop the logger, download the entries, erase all logs, start logging again, repeat in 12 hours. P.S. We log a 2 byte version of RR interval-it stores a max of 92500 rr intervals before it overwrites. THX

Comment: @HelicOpter We are doing similar stuff as you, and would also like to have this feature as well. As there is no RTC we have to use the timestamps of the logbook entries to calculate the time of a RR values. We create new logbook entries every once in a while so we can read small chunks at a time. A problem to be aware of if the user takes off the device for longer than 60 sec or so remember to add "dummy" data. 

We also add higher resolution data, so it would be good be able to delete some logbook entries when done with them.